# Corda HSM - Support for SoftHSM

Tags: corda, hsm, softhsm

Corda has specific configurations mentioned for every HSM that they support. I have tried finding a way to directly configure the node to use softhsm. But I havent been able to find any thing for Corda to work with softHSM. 
Hyperledger Fabric has a config (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/hsm.html) that works with softHSM. 
Any ideas on if Corda can support softHSM and if yes what are the configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we currently do not support SoftHSM. We currently support:

1. Utimaco
2. Gemalto Luna
3. Futurex
4. Azure Key Vault
5. Securosys Primus X
6. nCipher nShield

Please refers to this list of supported HSM to use with. 
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.4/node/operating/cryptoservice-configuration.html#using-an-hsm-with-corda-enterprise

Comment: What about AWS CloudHSM ? The signing service has an example config for AWS CloudHSM listed. However it isnt present in the list of supported HSMs for Node.